# orientation issue on rotation in ios 8 when dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, presentviewcontroller

I am using mobiscan library for scan barcode. After complete barcode scanning I dismiss the current screen and force rotate to portrait mode. **At some moment a blank screen appear for some seconds and then display properly**. ***This issue is generate only in ios 8.*** It's working fine in ios 7. This issue is generate only when scan barcode in landscape mode.

Here are the code and snap of the issue which can generate in my app.

```
if(![UICommonUtils isiPad]) {
        // Force the iPhone or iPod to display the TableViewController in portrait mode.
        if (![self.presentedViewController isBeingDismissed])
        {
            UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            if (application.statusBarOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
            {
                UIViewController *c = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
                [c.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [self presentViewController:c animated:NO completion:^{

                    // Made changes for Issue#2 (When Compiler level flag -DUSE_AUTOLAYOUT=0) as per iOS8 Competibility.
                    if([UICommonUtils checkIfiOS8])
                    {
                        [self performSelector:@selector(dismissSheet) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }  
-(void)dismissSheet
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

[image: In snapshot show the issue after completion of barcode scanning.]

Any solution How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like the device status bar in is landscape mode. And your view somehow is in portrait mode.

Comment: thank u Sir, We solved this problem. But current issue is the app takes 0.6 seconds time for this screen after scanning completion. and client needs to reduce time to 0.3 seconds. any Suggestion?